# Assign appointmnet times in sync and async manner in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am working on a token management system. The tokens are issued in sync and async manner. In sync manner the tokens are issued based on the current time and the previous token's end time. It's basically queue. Whereas, in async tokens, the user can provide time in which he/she wants an appointment. So, the database will be checked and if that time frame is available, the token will be issued. 
My sync token are working perfectly fine. The problem is I am not sure how to synchronize the database with sync and async tokens.

For e.g, if some user asks for an async token at time 15:00:00 and some other user asks for time 14:00:00. Where the current sync tokens' latest end time is 12:00:00, how to insert that data in the table?

Note: There can be only one active token at a particular time either sync or async. Each transaction is assigned max 5 mins. The timings are calculated in the python script. The `bank_open` time is `10:00:00` and `close_time` is `18:00:00`

Here's the MySQL table:

```
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| id | type  | token                                | date      | start_time      | end_time        | no_of_trans |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 36 | sync  | 4059cdea-6e9d-4943-8d4c-f5df99d12ff5 | 2020-4-22 | 15:53:15.347864 | 15:58:15.347864 |           1 |
| 37 | sync  | 5b420dec-9fc2-415f-b2f2-3649a3c6fa26 | 2020-4-22 | 15:58:15.347864 | 16:18:15.347864 |           4 |
| 38 | sync  | 72501a99-c081-48ee-a05d-959499eeb944 | 2020-4-22 | 16:18:15.347864 | 16:33:15.347864 |           3 |
| 39 | sync  | 3d08050e-115f-4bb1-a98a-5991e87c4ead | 2020-4-22 | 16:33:15.347864 | 16:43:15.347864 |           2 |
| 40 | sync  | c19e664b-0df0-4149-8b13-98d7450ea72f | 2020-4-22 | 16:43:15.347864 | 16:58:15.347864 |           3 |
| 41 | async | 56a6f5bf-0f1a-4694-8c69-c67f7ed39147 | 2020-4-22 | 16:59:00.123456 | 17:04:00.123456 |           1 |
| 42 | async | bac9b649-4462-46cb-a290-df63cb4b7158 | 2020-4-22 | 17:00:00.123456 | 17:05:00.123456 |           1 |
| 43 | async | e9b12cf7-c03f-4d2a-a4a4-f19b0d7d50f3 | 2020-4-22 | 17:47:00.123456 | 17:52:00.123456 |           1 |
| 44 | async | e9b12cf7-c03f-4d2a-a4a4-f19b0d7d50f3 | 2020-4-22 | 17:47:00.123456 | 17:52:00.123456 |           1 |
| 45 | async | a04f1347-ec1d-469d-911a-7783658e1e71 | 2020-4-22 | 17:50:00.123456 | 17:55:00.123456 |           1 |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

And this is the schema:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| token       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_time    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| no_of_trans | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Currently, I'm checking these parameters in python script:

```
for i in range(len(async_end_list)):
  #print(async_start_list[i], '....', async_end_list[i])

  if (user_time >= async_start_list[i] and user_time <= async_end_list[i]):
    print("Wrong input")
    break

  if (user_time > async_start_list[i] and user_time > async_end_list[i]):

    if (end_time < bank_close and user_time > bank_open and user_time < bank_close and user_time > latest_sync_end_time):

      if (total_trans <= max_trans):
        mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tokens (type, token, date, start_time, end_time, no_of_trans) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", 
                        ('async', rand_token, today, user_time, end_time, no_of_trans))
        mydb.commit()
        print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
        break

      else:
        print("Maximum transactions for day has exceeded!!")
        break

    else:
      print("Record cannot be inserted.")
      break
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: This looks like MySQL and not Microsoft SQL Server. Can you confirm?

Comment: @tadman It's MySQL

Comment: Sample tokens could be a bit simpler